# How to Add E-mail Addresses in .php code

Tags: php

I am new to .php coding so I have tried to write this as code.  I would like to make just the e-mail addresses active but am not sure how to do this.

The Orpington Badminton Club Committee currently consists of 4 members who look after the day to day functioning of the club who are.

`[Removed Personal Details]`

Thanks

Comment: Further define what you mean by "active"

Comment: I just want to get the e-mail addresses under the names active thats all

Comment: i.e make them link into an e-mail account i.e. outlook

Comment: Sorry it was unclear im new here.  I will refer to the page

Comment: I had this answered by Travis action so could this be taken off hold please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just generate the following html:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com">Someone - Club Captain</a>
```

There is a reason that people use form submissions though to generate emails.

1. You are exposing your users emails to any program crawling the site. This is guaranteed to get your users email address on an incredibly large amount of spam mail list.
2. The html mail to links you find on websites are dependent on the user visiting the site having a default mail action selected in their browser. If they do not then they can click that link all day long and it will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly

Comment: @RobWheeler Don't forget to mark it as the answer and please heed the two warnings I've given. It may take longer to create a form submission and mailer from your server but it will save you time in the end when supporting clients after the fact.

Comment: Yes i will how do i do that

Comment: marking the answer

Comment: its unclear if these might be real people. You should replace the email address in your answer

Comment: @Cfreak very true, editing my answer to remove the details as well.

Comment: @Travis where do i mark the answer

Comment: @RobWheeler mark the greyed out checkmark next to the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks i have done that